# Could not load database driver: SparkEngineSpec

Tags: apache-superset

I'm using Superset 1.5.1 in  RHEL7.9 OS with Python 3.9.13
while connecting to the spark SQL from the superset I'm facing the following issues

> Could not load database driver: SparkEngineSpec

I have downloaded the required packages i.e. `pip3.9 install PyHive` and restarted the server but still facing the same error.

I have a couple of other environments with docker and with that, I'm able to connect to the same Spark SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after installing `sasl` packages

```
pip3.9 install sasl
pip3.9 install thrift_sasl
```